# Retain tag/field across events in logstash 1.5

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

I'm using logstash 1.5 to analyze logs.

I want to track two events which occur one after the other.
So I would like to set a flag/field/tag when first event occurs and retain the value across events.

I looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258164/logstash-keeping-a-value-across-events) but looks like grep and drop are not supported in logstash 1.5.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get with logstash is the elapsed{} filter.  You could use that code as a basis for your own filter if it doesn't meet your needs.  I also run some external (python) post-processing to do more than elapsed{} can (or should) do.